# class association

Tags: c#, associations, uml

I am working on a program that is supposed to simulate bank accounts.  I have my base class called "Investment", my two subclasses called "Stock" and "MutualFund", and I also have a class called "CustomerAccount" that is supposed to be associated with the base class "Investment".  [image: This is a picture of the classes and how they should be set up]

I'm not sure how to associate the CustomerAccount class with the Investment class.

Comment: @james: The `CustomerAccount` has a list of `Investment`s.

Comment: @Msonic, he's probably taking a beginner's C# class.

Comment: I am, this is for an intro C# class and this is for a windows form application

Answer (score 1):

The CustomerAccount class has a "CanHave" relationship with Investment.

In your CustomerAccount class, create a collection of Investments.  You could use a list to achieve this:

```
List<Investment> _investments;
```

Don't forget to initialize the list in your constructor.

```
_investments = new List<Investment>();
```

**Edit:**

Looping through the list:

```
foreach Investment invst in _investments
{
    if (invst.GetType() == typeof(Stock)) { }
    else if (invst.GetType() == typeof(MutualFund)) { }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I understand how to do that.  Is that all I would have to do?

Comment: Yep.  Because if you step back for a minute from your UML and think about the real world... people can have multiple investments.  One way to keep track of those is to keep a list of Investments.  If you want to track the investments separately, you could create a list for each subclass type. That might be a bit easier, because if you're iterating through the list of Investments, you're going to have to determine what type of investment it is, then cast it to that type so you can access subclass-specific properties and data elements.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having an account have `AddStock` and `AddMutualFund` it should just have `AddInvestment` which is then used to add either a stock or an inventment.  You then get all `Investment`s, rather than getting all stocks or mutual funds.

Comment: then keep a `List<Investment> investments` and all `AddInvestment()` has to do is `investments.Add(theNewInvestment)`. that is as "associated" that the two classes should be.

Comment: @jb. The OP posted another thread which he has since deleted.  In it he posted a bunch of code which already had a `List<Investment>` and used it as expected with the given methods.  Knowing that he already got that far, I didn't mention it here.